# How to get multiple deployment URLs in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: github, github-actions, environment

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that runs Playwright tests on every pull request, and I want to get the URLs of the two deployments associated with each pull request.

Here's an example of my workflow:

```
name: Playwright Tests
on:
  deployment_status:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to run tests against'
        type: environment
        required: true
jobs:
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Go to Dashboard directory
        run: cd apps/dashboard
      - name: Install Playwright
        run: npx playwright install --with-deps
      - name: Get deployment URLs
        run: |
            deployment_urls=()
            for deployment in "${{ toJson(github.event.deployments) }}"; do
             target_url=$(echo $deployment | jq -r '.target_url')
             deployment_urls+=($target_url)
            done
            echo "Deployment URLs: ${deployment_urls[@]}"
        id: get_urls
      - name: Run Playwright tests
        run: npx playwright test
        env:
          # This might depend on your test-runner/language binding
          DEPLOYMENT_URL1: ${{ steps.get_urls.outputs.deployment_urls[0] }}
          DEPLOYMENT_URL2: ${{ steps.get_urls.outputs.deployment_urls[1] }}
      - name: Upload Playwright reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: playwright-report
          path: playwright-report
```

However, when I try to access the `github.event.deployments` array in my workflow, it returns null. I have also tried using `github.event.deployment_status.target_url` but that only returns the latest URL.

I do not want to use any APIs to fetch those deployment URLs! Let me know if you require more details on this, Thanks!

**Update:**

I made changes to the workflow file, replacing `github.deployments` with `github.deployment`. Despite dumping the entire payload, it still only shows the most recent deployment.

Comment: You're not [setting the output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter). You have to write to `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Also, if you look at the [`deployment_status` payload](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#deployment_status) (which is what `github.event` contains), there is no field `deployments`. Just `deployment`. You can debug by dumping the entire payload: `jq . "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH"`

Comment: I debugged the entire payload and sadly it gives deployment detail of only the latest deployment!

Comment: If you need both URLs in the same workflow for _two_ deployments, then `on: deployment_status` won't work for you, since the payload for deployment status will only ever contain information of a single deployment. If you have two deployments, you should see different runs of this workflow for _each_ deployment.

Comment: @sytech can you describe more on what you mean by "you should see different runs of this workflow for each deployment"?